# Proof Verification: Prove if $s_n \rightarrow -1$ and $t_n \rightarrow 3$, then $s_n(t_n-1) \rightarrow -2$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

My work:

Given the stated convergence, by definition:

$\forall \epsilon_s\gt0, \exists N_s(\epsilon_s)\gt0 : n\gt N_s \rightarrow |s_n+1|\lt \epsilon_s $

and

$\forall \epsilon_t\gt0, \exists N_t(\epsilon_t)\gt0 : n\gt N_t \rightarrow |s_t-3|\lt \epsilon_t $

I want to show:

$\forall \epsilon\gt 0, \exists N(\epsilon)\gt0 : n\gt N \rightarrow |s_n(t_n-1) + 2|\lt \epsilon $

Analysis:

$\left| s_n(t_n-1) + 2 \right|= |(s_n+1-1)(t_n-3+2)+2|\lt|(\epsilon_s-1)(\epsilon_t
+2)+2|=|\epsilon_s \epsilon_t +2\epsilon_s-\epsilon_t|\lt|\epsilon_s(\epsilon_t+2)|+\epsilon_t$

choosing $\epsilon_{t_1} = 1, \epsilon_{t_2}=\epsilon, \epsilon_s=\frac{\epsilon}{6} $ implies for $N=max(N_{t_1}, N_{t_2}, N_s)$, $|s_n(t_n-1) + 2|\lt \epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

We have: $|s_n(t_n-1)+2| = |(s_n+1)(t_n-3) +2(s_n+1) -(t_n-3)| \le |s_n+1||t_n-3|+2|s_n+1|+3|t_n-3|$ . Hope you can take it to the end. Okay. Here is more details... as you ask for ...:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, $\exists N_1, N_2, N_3, N_4 > 0$ such that:
$n > N_1 \implies |s_n+1| < \sqrt{\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}$,

$n > N_2 \implies |t_n-3| < \sqrt{\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}$,

$n > N_3 \implies |s_n +1| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{6}$,

$n > N_4 \implies |t_n-3| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{3}$ .

thus if you take $N_0 = \text{max}(N_1,N_2,N_3,N_4)$ then if $n > N_0 \implies |s_n(t_n-1)+2| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{3} + \dfrac{\epsilon}{3} + \dfrac{\epsilon}{3} = \epsilon$.  Done !

Comment: So, is my proof wrong?

Comment: Mostlikely wrong !

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you want to prove manually the result that for any $s_n\rightarrow s$ and $t_n\rightarrow t$ we have
$$
s_n + t_n \rightarrow s + t
$$

The trick is to use the identity
$$
s_nt_n -st=(s_n-s)(t_n-t)+s(t_n-t)+t(s_n-s)
$$